# Access record row into Labels or specific data field into specific Label for pricelist

Tags: database, vb.net, ms-access, label, data-retrieval

I have an `access` database named "Contacts" inside: "PriceTable", this table has 3 columns: /Piece/Price/Material/ (obviously also"ID") with 24 preloaded records on it (6 of each material: -plastic, wood, steel, wax-). I want to load each record into labels to build into the form a **pricelist**
The third column "material" its just for try group in some way similar record types at runtime into 4 screen sections, but I have not idea also.:

To retrieve records on labels I research and found this code several times, creates the labels at runtime, but **I dont reach to get work**.

```
   Try
        Dim cn As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Contacts.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;")
        cn.Open()
        Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand
        cmd.Connection = cn
        cmd.CommandText = "Select * from PriceTable"
        cmd.Prepare()
        Dim Piece = cmd.ExecuteReader
        Dim posY As Integer = 100
        With Trabajos
            .Read()
            For Each item In Piece
                Dim newlab As New Label
                newlab.Name = item("ID")
                newlab.Location = New Point(25, posY)
                posy += 35
                newlab.Font = Font
                newlab.Text = .Item("Piece") + " - " + .Item("Price")
                newlab.Visible = True
                Me.Controls.Add(newlab)
                newlab.BringToFront()
            Next
            .Close()
        End With

        cn.Close()
    Catch
   End Try
```

Or maybe its easier create and locate 48 (independent `labels` 1 for piece and 1 for price of each item/record) then the problem is: **how to get specific records on specific labels?.** Using the ID?

pity that it is not so easy as:

```
Label1.text = Piece("ID"(2))
Label2.text = Price("ID"(2))
Label4.text = Piece("ID"(3))
Label5.text = Price("ID"(3))
```

anyone have some code?

Comment: If you're determined to use individual `Label` controls rather than a `DataGridView`, I would suggest that you add a `TableLayoutPanel` to your form and then add the other controls to it. That way, you don;t have to worry about positioning each control.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to use code you don't understand. Try just putting a DataGridView on your form and then use this code.

```
Private Sub FillDataGrid()
        Dim cn As New OleDBConnection("Your connection string")
        Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand
        Dim da As New OleDBDataAdapter
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        cmd.Connection = cn
        cmd.CommandText = "Select * From PriceTable;"
        da.SelectCommand = cmd
        da.Fill(dt)
        DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
    End Sub
```

Look up the objects I used to learn more about how to use a database in code.

Comment: @zackraiyan What? There is an overload of OleDBConnection constructor that takes a string. That string is the connection string. Also they are parentheses not brackets. Brackets look like [ ]

Comment: Sorry,my bad :( .... Hope u understand :) .... And why write so many lines like `cmd.connection=cn` ?? Tho i appreciate your knowledge

Comment: I spelled it out line by line to be more instructive instead of throwing everything into the various constructor. When I write my own I do use the constructors.

Comment: hope the OP finds our solution helpful :)

Comment: @zackraiyan @Mary Good suggestion but I really need to get specific values into specific labels instead a `Datagridtable` To show that `Labels` arranged as I want into the form.

**For this purpose its necessary to add datagridview?** (I must hide it I dont want a grid!), I know how to do that and how to fill that table from database, the problem is **how to get specific values into labels** from `DatagridView` or directly from the database (without datagrid) if its possible.

Comment: Seems its not possible directly from DB. the only way its add and fill a hidden datagridview, then:
`str = DataGridView1.Rows[DataGridView.SelectedRows[0].Index].Cells[X].Value.ToString();` 
Where X is the column you want to read.

Comment: @arc95 , take a look at my answer again

Comment: I solved just inserting table, then:

`Label1.text = PreciosTableDataGridView.Rows(1).Cells(1).Value`

Answer (score 0):

You can go with a `DataTable` but a `DataReader` is proven to be faster than a `DataAdapter`.Try out the following code snippet :

```
  '''''create a class to handle all the data
  Public Class MyData

Private age1 As Integer

Public Property Age As Integer
    Get
        Return age
    End Get

    Set(ByVal value As Integer)
        age = value
    End Set
End Property

Private name1 As String

Public Property Name As String
    Get
        Return name
    End Get

    Set(ByVal value As String)
        name = value
    End Set
End Property

Private id1 As Integer

Public Property Id As Integer
    Get
        Return id
    End Get

    Set(ByVal value As Integer)
        id = value
    End Set
End Property
End Class


'''Then we create an Array-list

 Dim data as New ArrayList

'''Then we just use a datareader

  Dim cn As New OleDBConnection("Your connection string")
  Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand("YOur sqlCommand here",cn)
  DIm dr as SqlDataReader = cmd.executeReader
  While dr.read 
    Dim dt as New MyData
    dt.Id = dt(0)
    dt.Name = dt(1)
    dt.Age = dt(2)
    data.Add(dt)
  End while

  '''Then we set the dataGridview's datasource

   dataGridView1.DataSource = data
```

But if u really want to use labels to display the data,then do this :

```
 Dim dt as New DataTable ....
 ....
 ......
 da.Fill(dt)
 Label1.Text = dt(0)(1) '''0 i row count , 1 is column count , change it per your requirement
```

Comment: Now, this is not going to compile.  Dim cn As New OleDBConnection = "Your connection string"

Comment: @zackraiyan The class gets an error at the second declaration of each one, says: `"Age is already declared as 'private age as integer' in this class."``

Comment: You are getting you C# and vb wires crossed. VB is case insensitive.

Comment: Why marry,what did i do wrong :( ?? C# is case-sensitive,not VB

Comment: in vb.net only `String`s are case-sensitive

Comment: @zackraiyan Every one of your backing fields and property names in your class are the same! This will not compile in VB. Case insensitive VB, ID and id are the same! You must be thinking of Case sensitive C#.

Answer (score 0):

I used TextBoxes set to Read Only because they are easier to see and line up at design time. Then I made lists for each column you want to display. I only did three records but you will need to all 24 so each list will have 24 elements. Then loop through data with the DataReader filling the text boxes. In the dr.GetString(1), the 1 refers to the zero based index of the column. For the price you probably will use dr.GetDouble(index of the price column)

```
Private Sub TestControlArrays_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim PriceBoxes As New List(Of TextBox)
        Dim PieceBoxes As New List(Of TextBox)
        PieceBoxes.Add(TextBox1)
        PriceBoxes.Add(TextBox2)
        PieceBoxes.Add(TextBox3)
        PriceBoxes.Add(TextBox4)
        PieceBoxes.Add(TextBox5)
        PriceBoxes.Add(TextBox6)
        Using cn As New SqlConnection("Your Connection String")
            Using cmd As New SqlCommand("Select * From Price", cn)
                cn.Open()
                Dim dr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
                For x As Integer = 0 To 23
                    dr.Read()
                    PieceBoxes(x).Text = dr.GetString(1)
                    PriceBoxes(x).Text = CStr(dr.GetInt32(0))
                Next
                cn.Close()
            End Using
        End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: The correct order of my table is:
ID/Piece/Price/MAterial
Then the correct code must be:
`PieceBoxes(x).Text = dr.GetString(1)
 PriceBoxes(x).Text = CStr(dr.GetDecimal(2))`

At access the "price" colum  has currency format  but gets error < "the conversion is not valid" then i change the column property into number, but the same error, finally I format as "text" but same. if I use `PriceBoxes(x).Text = dr.GetString(2)` I get "index out of range"

Comment: My code: https://1drv.ms/f/s!AlqVaIM2GTrSlz6rOf9r7jXxnsBB

the problem is at: "Precio" form

Comment: Which form are we looking at?

Comment: "Precio" form is where I implement your code at Line 131-150 I just try with 3 items

Comment: Your code looks fine. Just add the rest of the labels and check the datatype of the Price to be sure it is a string.

Comment: Please confirm... You have 40 records in the database. You have added 80 labels to the form. You have added all 40 labels to the Piece list and 40 labels to the Price list. What is the error and on what line does it happen. If no error what are you observing?